Anaconda build string starting with "pypi..."
In an anaconda requirements.txt, I have several dependencies with build strings that start with pypi....
  - argon2-cffi==23.1.0=pypi_0
  - appdirs==1.4.4=pypi_0
  - anyio==4.2.0=pypi_0
  - annotated-types==0.6.0=pypi_0
  - altair==5.2.0=pypi_0
  - ale-py==0.8.1=pypi_0
  - adjusttext==1.1.1=pypi_0
  - accelerate==0.27.2=pypi_0

What does this mean? On stackoverflow, people say the build string starts with the version of python used to build the package. But pypi is not a version of python. Also, the conda documentation says nothing about what the build string prefixes mean.

According to the official documentation, the pypi part of the build string means that the package is sourced from PyPI and installed by pip, rather than from a conda-managed channel. Quoting the documentation:

For example, if we create an environment with conda:
conda create -y -n some_pip_test python=3.7 imagesize=1.0

Then we update imagesize in that environment using pip:
conda activate some_pip_test
pip install -U imagesize

...
Conda 4.6.0 now shows only one entry for imagesize (the newer pip entry):
imagesize                 1.1.0 pypi_0    pypi



Ok, how do you create a conda environment with these dependencies installed? conda create doesn't seem to like dependencies with a build string of "pypi", and pip install doesn't like requirements.txt files with conda build strings. Can you set pypi as a channel in conda?

IMO that's a separate question that should be asked (and which you already asked I believe). I suspect that the format which that repository provides is not compatible with conda. Again, I think you need to contact the author of that repository to see what they actually did and how they got it to work. That said, if this answered the question in this post, I'd appreciate accepting it so that this question can be marked as done :-)
